# Autenticación con Json Web Token

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, webapi

Para el proyecto en el que trabajo requiero de una Api que autentique a un usuario y me regrese un token, lo cual ya he logrado de forma sencilla, también logré autenticar una Api y al hacer peticiones mediante el sistema Postman, todo transcurre según lo esperado. Sin embargo, a la hora de intentar autenticar una aplicación Asp.Net Core MVC el sistema no se comporta de la misma manera ya que no autentica al usuario.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<bd_parContext>(item => item.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("local")));
        services.AddScoped<IUsuarioServicio, UsuarioServicio>();
        services.AddCors(opciones =>
        {
            opciones.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials().Build());
        });
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(opciones =>
            {
                opciones.SaveToken = true;
                opciones.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                };
            });
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

El código anterior corresponde a la clase Startup de la Api que genera el Token.

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "RequestVerificationToken");
        services.AddSession();
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(opciones =>
            {
                opciones.SaveToken = true;
                opciones.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                };
            });
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = "JwToken";
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(500);
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Sesion}/{action=InicioSesion}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

El anterior código corresponde a una aplicación MVC. (Cliente)

```
            var post = http.PostAsJsonAsync("https://localhost:44326/api/Sesion/IniciarSesion", usuario);
        post.Wait();
        var resultado = post.Result;
        if (resultado.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string stringJWT = resultado.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Jwt token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Jwt>(stringJWT);
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("JwToken", token.Token);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Prueba");
        }
```

El fragmento anterior corresponde al método de inicio de sesión utilizado en el controlador del cliente MVC, tras debuggear el método puedo observar que el token es devuelto exitosamente, pero a la hora de navegar a la siguiente pagina muestra un error 401.

Pd: llevo varias días investigando y no encuentro hacer esto. Ya las primeras 10 páginas de Google me muestran todos los enlaces en morado. T_T

Comment: Debuggeaste? donde da el error? que devuelve?

Comment: El código no retorna ningún error. Genera el token de forma correcta y lo guarda en HttpContext.Session, pero si le agrego la etiqueta [Authorize] a algun controlador del cliente, no lo autentica, directamente me salta el mensaje 401, de igual modo si remuevo la etiqueta e intento consumir una Api que se encuentre protegida, al no autenticar me impide consumirla.

Comment: pobaste con ValidateLifetime = false?
probaste habiltando los cors? que backend usas?
Tenes algun perfil declarado en el token? y al que no le estes dando permiso en el back?